# Fritz Online will not finish game?

Tags: fritz

Fritz Online will play all the way to the point where there's mate in one move.  In other words, if you are white and Fritz is black it will stop playing (moving) at the point any black move will be followed by mate on the part of while.

This is fine, I can read the Fritz console in the lower right and it will say something like "White mates".

The problem is that I want my kids to play with Fritz Online and this modality is disorienting to them.  They want to see the game play through to the actual end and get the satisfaction of completing the mate.

Is there a setting that will cause Fritz Online to play through to the end just like any regular chess program?

Answer (score 1):

Just tested it and it may have been fixed. It let me complete the mating move.

Just in case, the site is https://fritz.chessbase.com/